Using grep in .gitlab-ci.yml to find a line
In my .gitlab-ci.yml file, I have the line
- if: '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[release\]::/'

The line is used to check for commit message that starts with [release]:: and follows gitlab yml convention where regex expression must start and end with a / character.  The line is working properly for what it is supposed to do as tested and verified.  So, that is all good.
Next, I want to write a Gitlab CICD  job that will verify that this line exists in .gitlab-ci.yml file.  To do so, I tried creating a job like this
check-job:
  stage: check
  script:
    - |
      #!/bin/bash
      if ! grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[release\]::/' .gitlab-ci.yml; then
        echo "missing line starting with [release]::"
        exit 1
      else
        echo "found line starting with [release]::"
      fi

This however does not work but I am sure it has to do with \[ part of regular expression.  This is because if I remove \[release\]::/, and check for:
grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^' .gitlab-ci.yml

, it will work.

Isn't there  a flaw in this approach? Won't the grep command find itself in the gitlab-ci file and assume all is well? That is, the check-job job contains the string you have specified, but it is not part of the behaviour you want to ensure.

@Dunes Haha, good catch. I think there are some cases where this wouldn't be a problem (e.g. when check-job is defined in another .yml file which is only included into the .gitlab-ci.yml using gitlab ci's include: syntax) but you should definitively consider that problem like all the other false-positive and false-negatives of such a check.

It's probably a better idea to move this check into your unit tests. Have the test read the file, parse it as yaml and then assert that it has a job called release or whatever, that has a guard with a specific and exact value. It's easier to assert the structure of a yaml blob/dictionary then it is "free" text. That way you can be more precise about the behaviour you are looking for / intending.

The problem with grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[release\]::/' is, that it interprets special symbols like \ too, but you wanted to search for them literally, without this special meaning.
Instead of painstakingly escaping the special symbols (and having to read that escaped version later), I'd recommend to use grep -F which searches for literal strings instead of regexes.
grep -F '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[release\]::/' .gitlab-ci.yml

Please note that your grep command is only a heuristic.
On one side, both yaml and gitlab-ci syntax would allow to write an equivalent rule using a slightly different string.
One the other side, users can trick your check by adding the requested string as a comment or something like that. As pointed out by @Dunes, the grep command might even find itself.
To work around the last two problems, you could use ...
grep -Eo '^[^#]+' .gitlab-ci.yml | grep -Fv 'grep' | grep -F '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[release\]::/'

The first heuristic (!) removes (trailing) comments, the second one the grep command itself, and the last one searches for your string in the remaining parts.
Just like before, this is only a heuristic.
Resolving all such problems seems too hard. You would need not only a yaml parser and a parser for gitlab-ci files, but also an interpreter (!) for the latter, as users could define things like include: $VARIABLE.yml.
I recommend a manual review process using protected branches, merge requests, and maybe CODEOWNERs

Yes, that works but the problem with that is that it will detect 2 lines, one that I am looking for and another line that is in my job (your correction to my problem).  Also, if my line (the one I am looking for is commented out (in yml, that is #), it will still find it.  Any idea how to fix these to issues; otherwise, your suggestion works, thank you so much

... looks like using grep -F m 1 '...' fixes the 1st problem I described above.  But still dont know how to not match commented out lines.

@pixel I added some notes on that. I wouldn't recommend -m1 -- it doesn't really solve the problem. For the comments, you could add even more heuristics, but for a better solution, you need at least a yaml parser. I like fq (a generalization of the jq command, which only works with JSON).

Thank you for your help.  I think I solved it with your help by using following if statement if ! grep -F -m 1 '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\[release\]::/' .gitlab-ci.yml | grep -v '^#'; then.  As you helped a lot, if you modify your answer to include that, I will accept it as an answer.  BTW, your 2nd suggestion to add | grep -v grep must be wrong, I think you wanted to say | grep -v '^#'

"grep '$...' will never return any matches, no matter the input, because after the end of the line, there cannot be any more characters." This is my understanding too. However, the question states that this grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^' .gitlab-ci.yml works. What could explain this?

@pixel I'm glad I could help. I added a slightly improved command which also handles trailing comments. The (now gone) suggestion with grep -v grep was working as intended. It was used to exclude the false-positive from grep finding itself. The grep -v '^#' you suggested handles comments. The old version of my answer did not try to handle comments in any way.

@user202311 Thanks for the note. I overlooked that detail. I was able to reproduce this with GNU grep and busybox grep. Seems to be a feature of the BRE syntax. Apparently, POSIX specifies that $ matches the ending position of the string, if it is the last character of the regular expression. When using grep -E (ERE syntax) it doesn't work anymore. I'll edit my answer.

You need to escape backslashes and left [ :
if ! grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\\\[release\\]::/' ...


I'm sorry I downvoted this answer. Apparently, it actually works (oh the irony, looking at what I commented before...). For BREs, POSIX specifies, that $ only has a special meaning when used at the end of the pattern -- which is good in this case.
If you edit your answer somehow, I'd like to remove my downvote.

This actually does not work for me.  I used this command and supplied file name like if ! grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\\\[release\\]::/' .gitlab-ci.yml and all it does is, it shows > prompt and cursor expecting some user input

because of the if at the beginning, bash is expecting a then; ...; fi. Philippe left out that part, because it is the same as in the question

Yes, I have full if ...; then ... fi.  I am saying that the grep command is not working for me

@pixel Thank you for reporting back on this even after your original problem was already solved. ¶ You said that something was waiting for user input. I strongly assume that it is bash, because you were shown a > prompt -- Allgrep implementations I know wouldn't print a prompt when waiting for input. If bash is waiting for user input, this means grep did not run yet, or already terminated. ¶ I tested Philippe's grep command and it worked for me, see https://onlinegdb.com/DdPrp7XrI

@Socowi Either I mistyped Phillipe's suggestion or it was corrected afterwards.  Yes you are correct, it is working for me now as grep '$CI_COMMIT_MESSAGE =~ /^\\\[release\\]::/'.  I am on grep 3.1

@Socowi Thank you for following up on this! pixel, I have not changed the script.
